# C++: how to convert std::vector to Eigen::MatrixXd?

Tags: c++, eigen, stdvector

I have `std::vector<double> param` with (n + n * n) length and I need to move  last (n * n) elements to MatrixXd. I did it in this way:

```
MatrixXd cov(n, n);
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) {
    for(int c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c) {
        cov(i, c) = param(n + i * n + c);
    }
}
```

Is there better way to do this?

Edit: better means faster ;)

Comment: You can use Map. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you guarantee that the vector stores its elements contiguously, the simplest and fastest way is the following:

```
std::vector<double> param;
//code//
.
.
.
//code//
double *v = &param[n];
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> matrix(v,n + n * n,1);
```

In this way the memory of param is reused.

Comment: std::vectors always store their elements continuously in memory

Comment: Thanks! It is working but in fact there should be:
`double *v = &param(n);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> matrix(v, n, n);`

Comment: Only ..[n].. works out in Mac. I don't know why.  double *v = &param[n]; Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> matrix(v, n, n);

Answer (score 7):

[Roger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40853254/2899559) is good, with the exception that if you want to utilize vectorization, the `Eigen::Map` doesn't know if it's aligned or not, thus no vectorization. If you want that, you need to make a **copy** of the data and not just map to it.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd copiedMatrix = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(&param[n], n, n);
```